# On Jetpack Joyride, right after I cashed in the medal my game changed to my brother's, who has the same Apple Id

Tags: jetpack-joyride

When I play Jetpack Joyride I end up on my brother's game, who has the same Apple Id as me. I tried closing the app several times and shutting off my iPad but nothing worked. It happened right after I cashed in my medal.

Comment: I suspect, if you share one apple ID, they likely merged the two games, especially if you need to log into the apple id to play.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to my Clash of Clans account. My friend and I had same Game Center, changed Game Center but the data was still stuck on his iPad so he still had access to my game on his iPad and Game Center. I would delete all of the info from your brother's iPad and then re-download it.